# An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a new empty page and when I'm trying to view that page, the error page like this is shown:

[image]

This is the page source:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test12.aspx.cs" Inherits="AEIC.Test12" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace AEIC
{
    public partial class Test12 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Works by :

1- Set the "Build Action" to Content

2- Set the "Copy to Output Directory" to Copy always

It's all about the <%@ Page %> tag.

A couple other solutions:

1. Use CodeFile instead of CodeBehind (but keep in mind that this exposes your source code in plain text and compiles at run-time);
2. Ensure that your Inherits attribute includes the correct Namespace if one is used. You can find this in the Project Properties page under the Application tab

Comment: I tried your first 2 solutions, didn't work. It's not a good ideal to use code file, is it possible to a new form created by visual studio uses a wrong namespace?